# How do I limit, or reject the delivery of mail to a lotus notes mail file to only specific hours of the day?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, restrictions

How do I limit, or reject the delivery of mail to a lotus notes mail file to only specific hours of the day?  I only want the mail file to accept delivery of mail during specific hours of the day.  During the other hours I want the sender to get a delivery failure message.  Possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question really belongs on ServerFault rather than SuperUser since it's a server admin question.  It might even belong on StackOverflow since all solutions I can think of will involve writing code.

For the purposes of this answer, I'm assuming that this is a user mail file, not a mail-in database that you are talking about. If it's a mail-in database, the work is similar.  I'm also taking you literally about wanting to send back a non-delivery notification and require the sender to re-send later. (I wouldn't do it that way myself. I would put the messages into a temporary holding database and then release them to the actual destination database at the appropriate time.)

To do what you want, you need to write three agents.

The first agent would be scheduled to run at the time you want to stop delivery. This agent would modify the Person document, changing the mailfile to point to a mail-in database.

The second agent would be set up to run after new mail is delivered to the mail-in database. Its job would be to send back a non-delivery notice. I don't think you want a generic non-delivery to go back to the sender. You could do that by having the first agent set the mailfile to a non-existant filename, but the non-delivery generated by that would probably just make the senders think they sent to the wrong address, so they'd try again or call your help desk and be very unhappy. You should have a custom message that says "This message cannot be delivered between the hours of X:00 and Y:00. Please re-send it later."  That's exactly what this agent should do.

The third agent would be scheduled to run at the time you want to start accepting messages again. It would modify the Person document, setting the mailfile field back to the correct value. If you wanted to be nice to the senders, and not make them re-send the message, you could have this agent re-send the messages. After all, they're still stored in the mail-in database (unless you coded the second agent to delete them).